# Rich text box on a pdf with AcroFields ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using C# and ITextSharp.
I need to generate a PDF document based on a key / value dictionary.

Everything works, except for values from a rich text box.

here is my code :

```
Output.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = false;
Output.AcroFields.SetFieldRichValue(key, value);
```

I tried different values (here is an example)

```
<p><em>No rece</em>nt c<s>hanges in marital st</s>atus or dependen<strong>ts test</strong></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h2><s><em><strong>Hello !</strong></em></s></h2>
```

And only an empty field appears on my PDF...

Any idea why ?

Comment: The richValue of a field with richText set is actually an array of span objects (see Acrobat JavaScript documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example richt text string in the PDF specification looks like a more complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xfa:contentType="text/html" xfa:APIVersion="Acrobat:8.0.0" xfa:spec="2.4">
  <p style="text-align:left">
    <b>
      <i>
        Here is some bold italic text
      </i>
    </b>
  </p>
  <p style= "font-size:16pt">
    This text uses default text state parameters but changes the font size to 16.
  </p>
</body>
```

*(Section 12.7.3.4* Rich Text Strings *in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

You might want to start your tests using such an example.

Furthermore `AcroFields.SetFieldRichValue` returns a Boolean result indicating whether iText(Sharp) thinks setting the value had succeeded. You might want to check this result, too.